# I calculated the vector magnitude and angle but the text book I got it from stated the latter is different.

Tags: vectors, angle

Assume the following fact: If an airplane flies with velocity V(a) relative to the air and the velocity of the wind is W then the velocity vector of the plane relative to the ground is *V(g) = W + V(a)*.

Now suppose that the Wind is blowing from the North-East at 50 mi/h and that the pilot wishes to fly due East at 500 mi/h. What should the plane's apparent velocity vector V(a) be?

My issue with this problem, isn't that I didn't get an answer at all, I got a vector of magnitude 537 approximately which is correct, but I got an angle of around 4 degrees but the text book says that its 86 degrees. I can't find where I went wrong in that calculation. Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that $86+4=90$ is a hint that your angle measurement conventions are off-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the coordinate system has the zero angle in the North direction. Going to East is at $90^\circ$. My guess is that you calculated that you have $4^\circ$ angle with respect to the East direction. The angle with respect to North is $90^\circ-4^\circ=86^\circ$

Comment: Ok..quick question, how can you tell that the zero angle is in the North direction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass#/media/File:Compass_Card_B+W.svg or look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass "North corresponds to 0°, and the angles increase clockwise, so east is 90° degrees, south is 180°, and west is 270°. "

Comment: Oh! I'm an idiot! I assumed the same angle convention as the xy-plane. Thank you so much!